# Parsing Chef cookbook using jclouds failed

Tags: jclouds

I need to process cookbook metadata. I'm using jclouds to do this, but the apache2 cookbook fails with error message "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line ...". I've tried versions 1.8.4 and 1.9.6 uploaded from http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apache2.

The code looks like this:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(content);
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
while (entry != null) {
  if (entry.getName().endsWith("/metadata.json")) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<Metadata>() {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Metadata metadata = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(zis, Charsets.UTF_8), type);
    ...
  }
}
```

I've debug the problem and it looks like the gson failed on "default" attribute (Attribute class) which is expected as JsonBall (the defaultValue class field), but in the metadata.json it is a plain string.

Please, cloud you point me to a solution or simple example how to do it right? Or let me know if it is an issue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while now, but I've just seen this question.
The issue was reported in the jclouds issue tracher and should be already fixed:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-377

Could you try using the last 1.7.1 or 1.7.2 jclouds release?